# How to solve the running principal based on running ac_principal?

Tags: mysql, sql

Here's my sample query problem

```
+-------+----+-----------+--------------+------+
| id    | SN | principal | ac_principal | stat |
+-------+----+-----------+--------------+------+
|  1001 |  1 | 280       | 280          | paid |
| 10001 |  2 | 280       | 280          | paid |
| 10002 |  3 | 280       | -280         | NULL |
| 10003 |  4 | 280       | NULL         | NULL |
| 10004 |  5 | 280       | NULL         | NULL |
| 10005 |  6 | 280       | NULL         | NULL |
| 10006 |  7 | 280       | NULL         | NULL |
| 10007 |  8 | 280       | NULL         | NULL |
| 10008 |  9 | 280       | NULL         | NULL |
| 10009 | 10 | 280       | NULL         | NULL |
| 10010 | 11 | 280       | NULL         | NULL |
| 10011 | 12 | 280       | NULL         | NULL |
| 10012 | 13 | 280       | NULL         | NULL |
| 10013 | 14 | 280       | NULL         | NULL |
| 10014 | 15 | 280       | NULL         | NULL |
+-------+----+-----------+--------------+------+
```

Here's the output that i want to show

```
+-------+----+-----------+--------------+------+
| id    | SN | principal | ac_principal | stat |
+-------+----+-----------+--------------+------+
|  1001 |  1 | 280       | 280          | paid |
| 10001 |  2 | 280       | 280          | paid |
| 10002 |  3 | 280       | -280         | NULL |
| 10003 |  4 | 560       | NULL         | NULL |
| 10004 |  5 | 280       | NULL         | NULL |
| 10005 |  6 | 280       | NULL         | NULL |
| 10006 |  7 | 280       | NULL         | NULL |
| 10007 |  8 | 280       | NULL         | NULL |
| 10008 |  9 | 280       | NULL         | NULL |
| 10009 | 10 | 280       | NULL         | NULL |
| 10010 | 11 | 280       | NULL         | NULL |
| 10011 | 12 | 280       | NULL         | NULL |
| 10012 | 13 | 280       | NULL         | NULL |
| 10013 | 14 | 280       | NULL         | NULL |
| 10014 | 15 | 280       | NULL         | NULL |
+-------+----+-----------+--------------+------+
```

*note: the (-280) in ac_principal must be add to principal of (280) in SN=4 so the new principal should be 560.

here's another sample...

```
+-------+----+-----------+--------------+------+
| id    | SN | principal | ac_principal | stat |
+-------+----+-----------+--------------+------+
|  1001 |  1 | 280       | 280          | paid |
| 10001 |  2 | 280       | 280          | paid |
| 10002 |  3 | 280       | -280         | NULL |
| 10003 |  4 | 560       | 560          | paid |
| 10004 |  5 | 280       | 280          | paid |
| 10005 |  6 | 280       | 280          | paid |
| 10006 |  7 | 280       | -280         | NULL |
| 10007 |  8 | 560       | -280         | NULL |
| 10008 |  9 | 840       | NULL         | NULL |
| 10009 | 10 | 280       | NULL         | NULL |
| 10010 | 11 | 280       | NULL         | NULL |
| 10011 | 12 | 280       | NULL         | NULL |
| 10012 | 13 | 280       | NULL         | NULL |
| 10013 | 14 | 280       | NULL         | NULL |
| 10014 | 15 | 280       | NULL         | NULL |
+-------+----+-----------+--------------+------+
```

Comment: Data set and result set do look pretty similar. I'm struggling to spot the difference.

Comment: Looks like `10003 |  4 | 560       | NULL         | NULL` it became 560 from 280 took some time for me as well.

Comment: so whenever ac_principal is negative the next record becomes principal -(previous ac_principal) ? eg: 280 - (-280) = 560

Comment: if the ac_principal is negative 280 then it will automatically add to next principal so that it will become 560

Comment: ah so it has to be an update statement?

Comment: select query statement...

Comment: sqlfiddle for those trying to do this: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3102e/1

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this?

```
   CASE
     WHEN (SELECT t.ac_principal FROM tbl1 t WHERE t.SN = SN-1) LIKE '-%') THEN principal - (SELECT t.ac_principal FROM tbl1 t WHERE t.SN = SN-1)
     ELSE principal
    END principal
```